# How to add a shadow under a navbar using CSS?

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav, effects

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to **HTML** & **CSS**> So, I reckon that this might sound easy to some of you.

I was looking for a way to add a simple shadow to the `navbar`, like the one on [Codecademy's web](https://www.codecademy.com/business) to my pre-existing `navbar`. I'm including the **HTML** & **CSS** of it in this [codepen](https://www.codepen.io/CodingAddict/pen/QWbmBVQ)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add a box-shadow to your nav bar. not to site-header.

```
nav {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

Comment: Tnx ! Can you explain what each element of that code does, technically ?

Answer (score 1):

Just update your CSS file from this:

```css
.site-header {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

to this:

```css
.site-header nav {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

or

```css
nav {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

Comment: I just tried adding that code at the very end of the CSS file, and it unfortunately did not work :( .